# Axis offset in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In Graphpad Prism, it is very easy to create an axis offset such as here:
[image: https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/statistics/index.htm?what_is_a_frequency_distribution.htm]

Somewhat hacky approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank()) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.2, xend = 4, y = -0.5, yend = -0.5 )) +
  geom_segment(aes(y = 0, yend = 8, x = 0, xend = 0 )) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

But this seems a bit too unflexible to me. I was astonished to not find a lot, if anything in SO about this. Google was rather frugal - I reckon I might not have quite used the right search terms.

Is there an (implemented) `ggplot` way which could reproduce this look?

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44621231/496488) might be helpful.

Comment: Or creating your own theme

Comment: @eipi10 indeed. I was not far from your option too :) I should have looked for 'gap', didn't think of this term. What do you reckon, shall I leave this post alive for search term purposes or delete ?

Comment: Let's leave it as a duplicate pointing to the other post. That helps future Googlers find stuff based on a wider array of searches.