# A theme for axis for ggplot2 - gap between x and y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, axis

I used the following code to generate a simple histogram:

```
d<-rnorm(1000, o, 1);
hist(d)
```

[image]

We can create similar axes setting in the base R plot command by using `bty="n"`.

My question: Is there any way in `ggplot` to create such an axes setting (the axes are not intersected at the origin)?

Farrokh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ggh4x package has [truncated axes](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/PositionGuides.html#truncated-axes-1) (Disclaimer: I wrote the package, so I'm not unbiased). By default, it cuts the axis off at the two most extreme breakpoints, but you can set different options.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(d = rnorm(1000))

ggplot(df, aes(d)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  guides(x = "axis_truncated", y = "axis_truncated") +
  theme(axis.line = element_line())
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Wow, this is a great "theme" - how does this actually work... are those actually scale bars? WOuld you mind adding this to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621231/how-to-make-gap-between-x-and-y-axis-and-protruded-ticks-in-ggplot2 to which this question I believe is a duplicate?

Comment: They are axis guides, just like the standard axes guides (and legends, colourbars etc.). I'm being a bit naughty here because ggplot2 hasn't officially opened up guides for extension packages (yet). I'll have a look at that question later today. Another way for adding them is `+ scale_x_continuous(guide = guide_axis_truncated(...))`.

Comment: @tjebo here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67165354/11374827